# then() not getting called while using bluebird promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I am trying to create a new `Promise` using `bluebird` library. The code for the same is as follows:

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('Promise created');
})
var myPromise = promise.then(function() {
    console.log('Then called');
});

setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('promise successful');
    console.log(myPromise);
}, 3);
```

But the control never goes inside the `then` block. I also see that the promise object does not have any fulfillment handler:

```
Promise {
  _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined }
```

How do i create a promise and link a `then` block to the same.

Comment: You need to actually resolve the promise.

Comment: You're never resolving the promise, so why would you expect fulfillment handlers to be called?

Comment: "*I also see that the promise object does not have any fulfillment handler*" - `myPromise` doesn't have any. `promise`, on which you called `then`, does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to be able to use the Promise you created you need to resolve and/or reject from within your Promise by calling each function respectively.

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject)) {      
    if (someWork) resolve(1);
    if (!someWork) reject(2);
}

promise.then(function(data) {
  console.log(data); // 1
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `resolve()` in the `Promise` function.